# AWS CDK sns Delivery status logging

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I have a scenario where I publish a message in a SNS topic and this message then is sent to SQS queue. What I want is to have logs in SNS everytime a message is sent to a subscriber (like my sqs queue). SNS being a passive component of AWS, logs are not generated automatically and must be set up through the feature "Delivery status logging". I have accomplished the set up through the AWS console but I would like to do it through the AWS CDK. I did not find anything in the documentation and either in examples through the web. Anyone already did that ?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid it can be done currently only via AWS SDK or management console: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html

> To configure topic attributes for message delivery status, you can use the AWS Management Console, AWS software development kits (SDKs), or query API.

I see no option to set it via CloudFormation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html

Answer (score 1):

Starting Dec-2023, SNS has added support for configuring delivery status logging via CloudFormation templates. Here's the feature announcement post: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/amazon-sns-configuring-delivery-status-logging-aws-cloudformation/

And here's how you do it:

```
"Resources": {
    "MySNSTopic" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Topic",
        "Properties" : {
            "TopicName" : "TestTopic",
            "DisplayName" : "TestTopic",
            "SignatureVersion" : "2",
            "DeliveryStatusLogging" : [{
                "Protocol": "sqs",
                "SuccessFeedbackSampleRate": "95",
                "SuccessFeedbackRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SNSSuccessFeedback_test1",
                "FailureFeedbackRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SNSFailureFeedback_test2"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```